# How to revoke Asana OAuth tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asana, asana-connect

Using Asana's NodeJS module (https://github.com/Asana/node-asana) with OAuth, is there anything I can do to revoke a user's access and/or refresh token?

Currently when a user tells me they want to disconnect from Asana, I just forget their tokens. But it seems like it would be more friendly to pass the word on to Asana too so they can clean up the data on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user wants to revoke authorization to an app they currently have to go through the app management screen (under account settings). This is an interesting suggestion - have you seen other APIs that do this in a way you like?

Comment: A couple examples are the APIs from Google and Evernote. I couldn't find a link that documents the Google API, but here's the commit where they added the API last year: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/1.0.3. And here's Evernote's API: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/UserStore.html#Fn_UserStore_revokeLongSession. I use both of these already and they work well. I was hoping to find the same thing for Asana.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I believe it's correct. But it would be great for Asana to add an endpoint for users to revoke their credentials. It's a significant oversight that users can establish OAuth connections to Asana from some remote service, but can't revoke them from that same context. Having to go to the Asana site and dig around in your settings kind of misses the point of OAuth.

Comment: @Ghazgkull ... except asana's everything is pretty discoverable ... but yeah I sort of agree